# MATLAB to C++ code row conversion

Tags: c++, matlab, reverse-engineering

I am not familiar to matlab, please help me to convert the third row of the following code snippet to C++.

(I've googled that **.*** is element-wise product, **(nbscales:-1:2)** is colon operator (like linspace),
 but still am stucked).

```
nbangles_coarse = 8; % just number, not data structure
nbscales = 6; % just number, not data structure

% please explain meaning of the next row
nbangles = [1, nbangles_coarse .* 2.^(ceil((nbscales-(nbscales:-1:2))/2))];
```

Which data structure is created? Either matrix or vector?

Comment: By default `[nbscales:-1:2]` creates a row vector. But I always prefer 1D vectors be column vectors.

Comment: If you have Matlab or Octave, you can copy/paste each part of that line of code, one piece at a time, and run it and see what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `nbscales:-1:2` generates the numbers 6 to 2, stepping by -1 (i.e.,
   `6 5 4 3 2`).
2. `nbscales-(nbscales:-1:2)` negates the vector `nbscales:-1:2` and adds 6 to each element to yield `0 1 2 3 4`.
3. `ceil((nbscales-(nbscales:-1:2))/2)` takes the previous vector, divides by 2 and rounds each element up to the next integer to yield `0 1 1 2 2`.
4. `2.^(ceil((nbscales-(nbscales:-1:2))/2))` takes the previous vector and raises 2 to each element in it, to yield `1 2 2 4 4`
5. `nbangles_coarse .* 2.^(ceil((nbscales-(nbscales:-1:2))/2))` multiplies each element by 8 to yield `8 16 16 32 32` (`*` yields the same result as `.*`).
6. Finally, `[1, nbangles_coarse .* 2.^(ceil((nbscales-(nbscales:-1:2))/2))]` just appends `1` to the beginning of that vector to yield `1 8 16 16 32 32`.

Note that `[1, nbangles_coarse * 2.^ceil((0:(nbscales-2))/2)]` yields the same result for all scalar values of `nbangles_coarse` and `nbscales`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an array:

```
exp_arr = (nbscales:-1:2)
ans =
      6     5     4     3     2
exp_halved_arr = (nbscales-exp_arr)/2
ans =

     0    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000
exp_halved_ciel_arr = ceil(exp_halved_arr)
ans = 
      0     1     1     2     2
arr_elementwise_exp = 2.^exp_halved_ciel_arr
ans =
      1     2     2     4     4
scaled_arr = nbangles_coarse .* arr_elementwise_exp
ans =
     8    16    16    32    32
% concatenate 1 at the beginning of the array
nbangles = [1, scaled_arr ]
ans = 
      1     8    16    16    32    32
```